# Passing cookies in Response.Redirect

Tags: cookies, vbscript, asp-classic, response.redirect

I work with Classic ASP (vbscript), I add cookies to the Response like so:

```
Response.Cookies("mycookie") = "var_cookie"
```

Then I issue a redirect to "etape2.asp" file:

```
Response.Redirect("etape2.asp");
```

On the new page ("etape2.asp") that I am redirected to, I try to retrieve a cookie like so:

```
Request.Cookies("mycookie");
```

But the cookie is empty!!

Can anyone think of why the cookies are not being passed?

Comment: Your browser cookie (privacy) settings or a third party add-on is blocking the cookies perhaps?

Comment: Is this code _before_ your opening `<html>` tag? Can you save and retrieve `Session` variables? Those are based on cookies as well, I believe. Also, what's with the semicolons?

Comment: This is before opening <html>. This problem is occured with "FireFox" by in "Chrome" is worked

Comment: If your applications are on different servers or are in different applications then the cookie may not be passed.

Comment: No, My applications are on same server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be worthwhile making sure you have set an expiry for the cookie far enough in advance, and set the path to which it applies:

So, in e.g. etape1.asp, do this...

```
var_cookie_mycookie                   =  "this is the contents of mycookie"

response.cookies("mycookie").expires  =  now + 1
response.cookies("mycookie").path     =  "/"
response.cookies("mycookie")          =  trim(cstr("" & var_cookie_mycookie))

response.redirect                        "etape2.asp"
```

And in etape2.asp, do this...

```
var_cookie_mycookie                   =  trim(cstr("" & request.cookies("mycookie")))

response.write                           "<p>Value of 'mycookie' cookie: " &_
                                         server.htmlencode(var_cookie_mycookie) &_
                                         "</p>"
```